# M_ss_ng Lette_s

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language, word-puzzle

Given [this list of all the words in english](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt) and a string with s_me missi_g lett__s, find one way to fill in the letters. Do note that some words on the list contain special characters (`! & ' , - . /`) and numbers

## Input:

[This list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt) and a string with missing letters.

The input sentence can contain or be missing any of these characters: `! & ' , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z`. An underscore is used to mark a missing character. All missing characters have a possible solution.

## Output:

One possible solution with all the missing letters fixed. Words split at a space . Case sensitive, includes words with `! & ' , - . /`

## Test Cases

Input: `a string with s_me missi_g lett__s`

All possible outputs: `a string with [same, seme, sime, some] missing letters`

Output Example: `a string with same missing letters`

Input: `A_ 6-po_nt A/_ ada__er`

All possible outputs: `[A., A1, A4, A5, AA, AB, AF, AG, AH, AI, AY, AJ, AK, AM, AO, AP, AQ, AS, AT, AU, AV, AW, Ax, AZ] 6-point [A/C, A/F, A/O, A/P, A/V]`

Output Example: `A. 6-point A/C adapter`

Input: `A_M AT&_ platform_s scyth_'s hee_hee_ he-_e! 2_4,5_t`

All possible outputs: `[A&M, AAM, ABM, ACM, ADM, AFM, AGM, AIM, ALM, APM, ARM, ASM, ATM, AUM, AVM] AT&T platform's scythe's hee-hee! he-he! 2,4,5.t`

Output example: `A&M AT&T platform's scythe's hee-hee! he-he! 2,4,5-t`

SemicolonSeperatedValue for first possible output:

```
a string with s_me missi_g lett__s;a string with same missing letters
A_ 6-po_nt A/_ ada__er;A. 6-point A/C adapter
A_M AT&_ platform_s scyth_'s hee_hee_ he-_e! 2_4,5_t;A&M AT&T platform's scythe's hee-hee! he-he! 2,4,5-t
```

## Scoring

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: I tried to made this really clear and well defined unlike the other similar questions, what about it is unclear?

Comment: @pfg how flexible is the input / output? can we work with a list of the words?

Comment: For test case purposes, can we have the 'words' list be `/usr/share/dict/words` instead of something on the web? `letters`, for example, is not in the standard unix `words` file (although `letter` is). That way, on TIO you can use the local file.

Comment: @pfg i meant the 'Words split at a space' part, the input/output can be separated words? Or we need to split / join the space?

Comment: So for `6-___nt` the only output is `6-point` and not the likes of `6-saint` etc?

Comment: ...yet it states "Words split at a space" in the output section and `-` is not a space.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sorry I didn't search the list. `6-point` is the only option for that

Comment: @pfg: TIO code is running on a virtual unix instance; so in python (for example) I can use `f=open('/usr/share/dict/words');W=f.read()` to access that standard unix file.

Comment: Will any words ever be *only* underscores?

Comment: @Οurous No. Possible special characters are `!&',-./`

Comment: Is it guaranteed that words without underscore are also always in the given word list?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>18 25 20</s>  19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

...noticed a bug during write-up, cost 7 to fix naively, then saved 5 with another approach to fix it.

```
LÞṗ⁹ḲL¤K€ḟ”_⁼œ&ʋ@ƇṪ
```

A dyadic Link accepting a list of lists of characters on the left (words) and a list of characters on the right (string) which returns a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n8LyHO6c/atz5cMcmn0NLvB81rXm4Y/6jhrnxjxr3HJ2sdqrb4Vj7w52r/v//H61kpluQn5lXoqSjoGSOYDrqO4MpPTBpCCITUxILSlJTEMwiODMfwizLT05MyQcxixNB5sT@h5muAKMd4@OVAA)**
...using a hugely restricted word list due to incredible inefficiency (although it could be far worse!)

#### How?

```
LÞṗ⁹ḲL¤K€ḟ”_⁼œ&ʋ@ƇṪ - Link: words, W; string, S
 Þ                  - sort (W) by:
L                   -   length (this is so we get final results which will match
                                in length when we use Ṫ at the end of the Link)
      ¤             - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
   ⁹                -   chain's right argument (S)
    Ḳ               -   split on spaces
     L              -   length
  ṗ                 - Cartesian power (all ways of making that number of words)
       K€           - join €ach with spaces
                 Ƈ  - filter keep those for which:
               ʋ@   -   last four links as a dyad with swapped arguments:
          ”_        -     literal '_' character
         ḟ          -     filter discard (remove all '_'s from S)
             œ&     -     (S) multi-set intersection (current value)
            ⁼       -     equal? (S without '_'s == multi-set intersection?)
                  Ṫ - head (last result)
```

Comment: Pinging this because I'm curious if theres a way to shorten the naive fix.

Comment: @Razetime Yes there was a way to do so, I've edited it in.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>96</s> <s>105</s> <s>99</s> 101 bytes

```python
lambda p,W:' '.join([w for w in W if all(map(lambda c,d:c in['_',d]and d,s,w))][0]for s in p.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BS8QwEIXP9lc892ASyLayqIfCHvoDvAk91DLETdpG0jYkkeKvr60ouB4G3rz53jz/mYZ5Oq3d@XV1anzTCl7WJQPL32c78WZBNwcssBNq2A7KOT4qz3/gi9TlZTs2jJjUrZo0tIxyEaJt7ts9Gveoz6N3NnEh1sWmAbM3E2fFRwxFHFQwhbaXVCxz0JFJsMAEVERfZjc1zujzYJTm4vdJlvlgp4SOs0FtvbX4awTt/nkKMW26x3d3pNFgtDFa6uFMSkTxmq8IT0c/07ZVBUFpRWTCFXOo6BnVyx1hMIb22cSRzC1O9CAfKR12ev0C)

`W` is the list of words which is set up separately; I'm using the `unix words` file on TIO, which doesn't contain `platform's` or `scythes's`.

Added 2 bytes for [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy).

Comment: The spec requires you to take the provided dictionary as input. It looks like you're using a different dictionary and assuming it's assigned to a predefined variable.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>232</s> 226 bytes

- -23 bytes from @ceilingcat
- +17 bytes for required header file

Like the other submissions, I used `/usr/share/dict/words`; change the first argument to select another wordlist and the second argument to specify the size (the function itself just needs an array of strings as the dictionary.) On a non-matched word with a `_`, the original word is returned.

```c
#import<string.h>
*g(s,t,u,v,w)char*s,**t,*u,*v,*w;{for(w=index(s,95)?0:s;(v=*t)&&!w;w=*u+*v?0:*t,t++)for(u=s;*u==95|*v==*u&&*v++&&*u++;);s=w?:s;}h(s,t,c,u)int*s,*t,*c,*u;{for(u=s;c=strtok(u," ");u=0)printf(" %s"+!!u,g(c,t));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZFLj9sgFIX38yuIq7q83HjSpE1Kmdl07WU21QhZ@IXq2JEvmErT@ev1XCfdgASX851zsFlr7bJ8cJfrOPkf4Cc3tJ@7pwfeUpBeBjnLyGxXThwk517yIPkseVSvzTjRqN1Q1X9w9HRgz/l3UHTW3LM03UQVNQ@Cz3iM77wQbH0RNCgetD4d/vJZ40Sa8lkIXIMQiinQ8Rll3rob3srA3OBXNqIt0u/cVcVqdOvH3zTIhCRMBZ2zK9r3DU3IR0jEZhNkS630jKk3jDjYPlQ1wZCVG9eMD5fSDbSQ5xuDn9XrLWijm/FaD/T8q3j68iKTKWEYHbQt@3609PBVFrr0o8OB3QsTj@ut12gxaHoTYCAKfsSe1OpVFVmWppRjA7ppaw9oeH@UDboKQu@PzDUUW7sXGeRjzhjDanKFornqkIImYI2wbANMW0BEva2c9ds4ThUs@2@n4@60GPBkZwwx2U/S1Z8MKcn9O0l0viNgLjW5OABnWtLX3hsD//f4zzZ92cKSxXc)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, 127 bytes

```java
L->s->{for(var x:s.split(" "))for(var w:L)if(w.matches(x.replace(".","\\.").replace("_","."))){System.out.print(w+" ");break;}}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##hVJNa9tAEL3nV0x1KCsqraG0PcSpwZTm5EDBvTVh2Mgrax1pJXZGlo3Rb3dXaxm3wWlBn@/NzJs3Oxu1Velm9XLMSkUED8rYww0AsWKTwcazsmVTyry1GZvayvvx4@7CzZ1T@4UhvluyM3Y9S64lfqsttZV256AZ5PAVjot0RunskNdObJWD3S1JakrDIoIojs9wd7uITS46WSnOCk1iJ51uSpVpEckoiR4fZRRfIPSQB@L4sNwT60rWLcvGy7LoPgyFp89Oq5dp3x@n3q2/mva59IZH39varKDysxCnZn89gYqHuQCw24uLO2Jfp5LL8Do7gxPq3YVAa2qZm1LLe/8gWRrr@/@b@aG4ILnW3vWkJTehQjk9WZmMJ13tVhSsBHmAf8wdQrDXtbq7FideYSQVBXy0wXWAhVebjmqsPR3KJhCpwZkXgs5wAYSVhsoQGVxDqZkRfaNXE@cIX9KmRsswnyColULU7s3gB5j/fI9QaI3D7T9S1O/gI35KPiO/kcZOWZLASDg0hBoZLYYYY/Gc1GfDAonvu0w3w1qCjg@9Z/rTGvx5/qH6f6edwOl3GM14RrlUTVPuT53FUmWD1jDjsYfXO1laEZj@pj/@Bg) (also uses the `/usr/share/dict/words` TIO word-library, which doesn't contain `platform's` or `scyth's`, but the lambda-function works with any kind of list String-List provided).

**Explanation:**

```java
L->s->{                   // Method with String-List & String parameters and no return-type
  for(var x:s.split(" ")) //  Loop over the parts of the input-String, split by spaces
    for(var w:L)          //   Inner loop over the words
      if(w.matches(x.replace(".","\\.")
                          //    Escape all dots
                    .replace("_","."))){ 
                          //    Replace all underscores with regex-dots
                          //    And if the current word matches it:
        System.out.print(w+" ");
                          //     Print the word, plus a space
        break;}}          //     And stop the inner loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>174</s> 171 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Text
$l=join" "o map(hd o filter(\w=any((==)w)l)o@o split"_")o split" "
@[h:t]|t>[]=[h<+c<+v\\c<-['0'..'9']++['a'..'z']++['A'..'Z']++['!&\',-./'],v<- @t]=[h]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBbS8NAEIXf8yvWtZiE3Prig5JIhVYQCgr1ySSEJdk0q3spu9PGir/duGloffvOzDmHYWpOiRyEavacIkGYHJjYKQ1oA81KHsI3@gXOjGcfikmMsLKendc1SKGWcaDaK/qMyKPnZZnf@9xXC4XMjjPAFfbPiLCzyLt7KH/gIS@zvEuDOg0ORVGnUe7O3Th279wyCHKXjPw98ePI7xNf3RRuGMWJW4aHNEILGFvKy61HA1TET4zTcEmAxCutlXY2QOyyV5o3zjXyXj4RZwbCaeKjDGlKmjG0ZpIahJO90YnpiKZJw2pIrK8x@FIwhm3IPgCBZuKk7dhYIbd2gcmZewYdMpWwH2XGsGqLOAWoKoOtv93LGpiSNjFzsn95qp8Kht@65WRrhuh5PSyPkghWT@KVE2iVFkPUDbfzufgD)

TIO link uses the dictionary in `/usr/share/dict/words` but it'll work with any list of words.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to turn the `@` helper into a fold, so if anyone has any ideas about that it'd be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#εD'_åiUʒX‚ζεD'_åsË~}P}Ω]ðý
```

Can definitely be golfed a bit more, but this will do for now.

First input is the string, second a list of words. If multiple words are possible, it picks a random one.

Assumes the sentence always contains at least a single space. If this is not allowed, the `#` has to be replaced with `ð¡`.

Uses the legacy version because the zip-builtins work on strings, whereas these have to be character-lists in the new version of 05AB1E. In the new version, the `ʒX‚ζεD'_åsË~}P}` would have been 1 byte longer because of that: `ʒSXS‚ζε'_åyË~}P}`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f@dxWF/X4w0szQ09NinjUMOvcNqhA8eHuutqA2nMrYw9vOLz3//9EheKSosy8dIXyzJIMheL43FSF3Mzi4sz4dIWc1JKS@PhirmilxKRkJR0lED@1CM4oBrJASqEU0AwgqzgxNxVEpUKoTAiVD6YS81JAJBCnpZaDdOUXgYSLgOL5uUBGeX5RSrFSLAA) (with a small sample dictionary list).

**Explanation:**

```python
#                   # Split the (implicit) first input-String on spaces
 ε                  # Map over each word:
  D                 #  Duplicate the current word
   '_åi            '#  If the word contains an underscore:
       U            #   Pop the copy and store it in variable `X`
        ʒ           #   Filter over the (implicit) second input-list of words:
         X‚         #    Pair `X` with the current word
           ζ        #    Zip/transpose, swapping rows/columns with spaces as default
                    #    filler if the strings are of unequal length
            ε       #    Map over each pair of characters
             D      #     Duplicate it
              '_å  '#     Check if the pair contains an underscore
             s      #     Swap to get the map-value again
              Ë     #     Check that both characters are the same
                 ~  #     Check that either of these were truthy
            }P      #    After the map: check if all pairs were truthy
        }Ω          #   After the filter: pop and push a random valid word
                    #  (implicit else: use the unmodified word from the duplicate)
 ]                  # Close both the if-statement and map
  ðý                # And join the list by spaces
                    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 22 bytes

```
wm`₁⁰w²
ḟoΛ='_żμ?'_³=⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/vzw34VFT46PGDeWHNnE93DE//9xsW/X4o3vO7bFXjz@02RYo8////0SF4pKizLx0hfLMkgyF4vjcVIXczOLizPh0hZzUkpL4@OL/0UqJSjpKEGUQRj6YAdKRX1oCZYFk8nNTk/JTKqFMEJUIpkAmgqhUoMFgrWArwCyQJalFxXAWlFGanKoUCwA)

For each word in query text, goes through all words in the dictionary substituting matching characters for `'_'`.
If, after doing this, the word is only `'_'`s, then it matched at all non-`'_'` characters, so it's a valid replacement.

````
 ḟoΛ='_żμ?'_³=⁰     # helper function: 
                    # finds word in arg2 that matches arg1 
                    # except at '_' characters.
ḟ                   # get first element that satisfies
 oΛ='_              # all elements are equal to '_'
                    # of
       żμ           # zip togethter arg2 and arg1 with
         ?   =⁰     # if they're equal
            ³       # then arg 2
          '_        # otherwise '_'
          
wm`₁⁰w²             # main program:
w                   # join with spaces
 m   w²             # map arg2 split on spaces 
  `₁⁰               # using helper function with arg1
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 53 bytes

```ruby
->d,s{s.gsub(/\S+/){d.grep(/#{$&.tr ?_,?.}/)[0]||_1}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY3PCoJAGMTvPcWH_UFJ3ToEXcybL9DRZCl2swU3Zb9vkVCfpItEPVRvk1mXGRh-M3N_Gnu69Y8kelk6B9v3JtgJHxsMc7Qnlx32S-Y1IsyNrFw2bWaLkAzE3I_DjnnpKmtbvu66f1kLiGBep0VppAZVodVQSCJpELRCVNcc8KglYDmIKAcOUBEMEWWTSWUJIUmFD84RkMwXrxVdAPmAjwM8Hwc5Ryf7nfb9zz8)