# Generate all Possibilities of Words

Tags: code-golf, string

This is not the same as [m-ss-ng-lette-s](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/164809/m-ss-ng-lette-s)

**Challenge:**

Given a string with masked characters, generate all possible words, inclusive of non-meaningfull words.

**Rules:**

- The sequence of the characters in the string does not change.
- The masked character (*) will be one of an English alphabets [a-z].
- There are no line breaks, space, numbers, special characters or punctuations.
- The output can be a list of non-meaningfull words too.
- Any characters in a string can be masked. Not necessarily alternating characters.
- For memory constraint, lets keep the maximum length of input as 10.

**Example 1:**

Input:

```
*o*
```

Output:

```
aoa
aob
aoc
...
...
...
boa
bob
boc
...
...
...
zoa
zob
zoc
...
...
...
zoz
```

**Example 2:**

Input:

```
*e*c*m*
```

Output:

```
aeacama
aeacamb
...
...
...
welcome
...
...
zezczmz
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main. I've edited out the fastest-code tag as it's a winning criterion tag and this is code golf.

Comment: fastest-code and code-golf are both [winning criterion tags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22371/100664). fastest-code means that the challenge is scored by the speed of solutions, by some metric; code-golf means that the shortest code wins. You can't have both.

Comment: Can delimiters between words be custom? E. g. use ` ` (space) instead of `\n`

Comment: We can stick to *, as space may create ambiguity when combining with other solutions.

Comment: I'd suggest allowing the masking character to be any non-alphabetical character. For most languages, the approach won't change, but the freedom of character is more likely to allow for the odd creative answer that only works for a specific masking character

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 25 bytes

```
eval echo ${1//\*/{a..z}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY7U8sScxRSkzPyFVSqDfX1Y7T0qxP19KpqayHyUGXLo5W08rWUYqFcAA)

Comment: Why not use `echo`?

Comment: @dingledooper `echo` won't print each of the word with a newline.

Comment: [25 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY7U8sScxRSkzPyFVSqDfX1Y7T0qxP19KpqayHyUGXLo5W08rWUYqFcAA) if using custom delimiters (in this case a whitespace) is allowed.

Comment: Nice solution, adding `>> Result.log` took care of large outputs.

Comment: Very nice.   Works in bash too with two escapes: `eval echo ${1//\*/\{a..z\}}` [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GCpaUlaboWu1PLEnMUUpMz8hVUqg319WO09GOqE_X0qmJqayEqoAqXRytp5WspxUK5AA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
mapM q
q '*'=['a'..'z']
q c=[c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzexwFehkKtQQV1L3TZaPVFdT0@9Sj0WKJBsG50cC5TPzLMtKMrMK1FQUUhTUNJK1UrWytVS@v8vOS0nMb34v25yQQEA)

Answer (score 8):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
->s{(?a..?z*10).grep /^#{s.tr'*',?.}$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664WsM@UU/PvkrLWFMvvSi1QEE/Trm6WK@kSF1LXcder1ZFv/Z/gUJatLpWvpZ67H8A)

The range is set to terminate after 10 `z`s, to fit the constraint. Realistically this takes forever to run unless a smaller number is used.

Comment: You need to add `^...$` to the regex, otherwise words longer than the input will be included (See `f['aa']` for an example)

Comment: @ovs fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 5 bytes

```
×kaVΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiw5drYVbOoCIsIiIsIltcIipcIixcInlcIixcInhcIixcIipcIixcImxcIl0iXQ==) Input as char lists.

```
   V  # Replace
×     # Asterisks
 ka   # With the lowercase alphabet
    Π # Take cartesian product
```

Comment: [Get outgolfed lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250546/92689)

Comment: @Steffan no, *you* get outgolfed lol

Comment: So the built-in for the string `"*"` is……… `×`???

Comment: @Fatalize Yep. I don't know why we have it, but it's occasionally useful.

Comment: @emanresuA But `*` is in the code page and is apparently multiplication… why not swap both symbols?

Comment: @Fatalize `*` has been around for a while, we're planning to make `×` multiplication in v3.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-n -M5.10.0`, 37 bytes

1 byte saved thanks to [@Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)!

```perl
$"=",";s/\*/{@{[a..z]}}/g;say<"$_\n">
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJFwiPVwiLFwiO3MvXFwqL3tAe1thLi56XX19L2c7c2F5PFwiJF9cXG5cIj4iLCJhcmdzIjoiLW5cbi1NNS4xMC4wIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIqbXkifQ==)

### Explanation

Turns the input into a `glob` (`<"$_\n">`) which is then evaluated as a list and printed (`say`) with newline separators.

**Note:** This does struggle to produce all the output for multiple `*`s when running on my phone!

Comment: save a byte using `say<"$_\n">` instead of `say for glob`

Comment: @Sisyphus Nice, I looked as using literal glob syntax, but not with a newline... Thank you!

Comment: If you just read from stdin (which you do with `-n`), `$_` will already have a newline, so you can ditch the `\n`. I guess in your "Try it online", there was no trailing newline in the input. (Add a newline, and you can ditch the `\n`)

Comment: @Abigail I've definitely utilised this in other answers for both requiring and requiring no terminating newline. I've [asked a question about what would be preferred](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25005/9365).

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, <del>88</del> 86 bytes

```python
def A(x):p=x.find("*");~p and[A(x[:p]+chr(i+97)+x[p+1:])for i in range(26)]or print(x)
```

Removed 2 bytes thanks to [@Adam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: You can remove `A(input())` - simply defining a function is enough by our rules.

Comment: Thanks! Should I add previous length to the title?

Comment: You can if you want, but no need :)

Comment: You can remove a byte by using `~x` instead of `x<0` and swapping around the conditions: `def A(x):p=x.find("*");[A(x[:p]+chr(i+97)+x[p+1:])for i in range(26)]if~p else print(x)`. You can remove another by replacing `if... else` with `and... or`: `def A(x):p=x.find("*");~p and[A(x[:p]+chr(i+97)+x[p+1:])for i in range(26)]or print(x)`

Comment: That's brilliant! Updated the code.

Comment: Thank you for the compliment, but most of these suggestions are just advice stolen from other people :) I'd recomment looking through [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) for some more great tricks.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
×Oka↔ƛ?×\%V$%
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiw5dPa2HihpTGmz/Dl1xcJVYkJSIsIiIsIipvKiJd)

[Could be 8 bytes by using `%` instead of `*`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiXFwlT2th4oaUdiUiLCIiLCIlbyUiXQ==)

Comment: When trying for "welcome", getting debug console message as "Code timed out after 10 seconds"

Comment: @GokulNathKP that's because the online interpreter is set to time out after 10 seconds. Either use a flag that increases the time out time or use the offline interpreter which doesn't have a time out limit

Comment: [Get outgolfed lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250528/100664)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 9 bytes

```
×Ẇ⌈yvkaYΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiw5fhuobijIh5dmthWc6gIiwiIiwiKnl4KmwiXQ==)

Based on emanresu A's answer, but shaves off another byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 65 bytes

```
f=\(s)`if`(grepl("[*]",s[1]),f(sapply(letters,sub,pa="[*]",s)),s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWNx3TbGM0ijUTMtMSNNKLUgtyNJSitWKVdIqjDWM1ddI0ihMLCnIqNXJSS0pSi4p1ikuTdAoSbaFqNDWBGGLQ3jQNJa18LSVNrpzUvPSSDI00DXWtVK1krVwtdU2oGpilAA)

Basically the same recursive idea as in [Cong Chen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250540/55372).

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 61 bytes

```
!s=join.(Iterators.product((x>'*' ? x : 'a':'z' for x=s)...))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjdtFYtts_Iz8_Q0PEtSixJL8ouK9QqK8lNKk0s0NCrs1LXUFewVKhSsFNQT1a3Uq9QV0vKLFCpsizX19PQ0NaGGuOek5qWXZGgoKmnlaylpKtTYKRQUZeaV5ORxKSrla-UrIYsg1KZqJWvlAtXX2EHlIMbB3AYA)

(This returns a matrix of all possible words, rather than a list/vector.)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Although I do not know much Julia, I suspect that you can remove some whitespace in there. Otherwise, it is a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
⊞υＳＦυ¿№ι*Ｆβ⊞υ⭆ι⎇⁻μ⌕ι*λκ⟦ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc1BCsIwEIXhvacYupoJ8QRdCoKLQkF34iLW1A7GSUkygqePVtH1@z/eMLk0RBdq7TVPqBZ2MmvZl8RyRaJ2NcYEqAQ8Am6iSkG20JiGCD7TmeBHv6pz85IcfBKXntixaMa7hS3L5W8tBAs3Wg58yB76tyx45BO1tZpo6voRXg) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υＳ
```

Start with the input string.

```
Ｆυ
```

Check each string.

```
¿№ι*
```

If it contains a `*`, then:

```
Ｆβ
```

Loop over the lowercase alphabet.

```
⊞υ⭆ι⎇⁻μ⌕ι*λκ
```

Replace the first `*` in the string with the current letter and push it to the search list.

```
⟦ι
```

Otherwise output the string on its own line.

23 bytes using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO:

```
⊞υωＦＳ≡ι*≔ΣＥυＥβ⁺κμυ≧⁺ιυυ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY6xDoIwEIZ3nuLS6UrKbnBydDAhMhqHUoE2ViBcK4PxKRxdGDTxAXwZ30YauOG_S-77_7vnR2nZq1bacXx7VyWr3yPzpNELGPg6qtoecNt03uWuN02NnAMNxikNaDjcIiWpBBazFDZEpm4w9xfcyS4EhFYIyKwnPAu48KkE-Cn2VFbSW5cGZPbtTa0dBlSAmaF7lE0nHU7ziwpFy4PfA0uulglgiQkatzE7Lrs_) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υω
```

Start with the empty string.

```
ＦＳ
```

Loop over the characters of the input string.

```
≡ι*
```

If the current character is a `*`, then...

```
≔ΣＥυＥβ⁺κμυ
```

... append each lowercase letter to each of the strings so far and join the resulting lists, otherwise...

```
≧⁺ιυ
```

... append the current character to each of the strings so far.

```
υ
```

Output the final list of strings.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 30 bytes

```
/\*/{%`$
25*$(¶$`
,Y0`*`l`\*.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/Xz9GS79aNUGFy8hUS0Xj0DaVBC6dSIMErYSchBgtPa3//7XytQA) Explanation:

```
/\*/{
```

Repeat while there are still any `*`s to process.

```
%`$
25*$(¶$`
```

Add 25 copies of each line.

```
,Y0`*`l`\*.*
```

Cyclically transliterate the first `*` on each line to the lowercase alphabet. The `,` tells Retina to process all matches and the `0` tells Retina to process the first character of each match.

Answer (score 3):

## [lin](https://github.com/molarmanful/lin), 49 bytes

```
"\*".?g.+_.+_"%s"?s.#t ?i len $a.~ `/\".t.~ sf"`'
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-lin) Returns an iterator of strings.

For testing purposes:

```
"*e*c*m*" ; \outln `' `_
"\*".?g.+_.+_"%s"?s.#t ?i len $a.~ `/\".t.~ sf"`'
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
"\*".?g.+_.+_ "%s"?s.#t ?i len $a.~ `/\ (.t.~ sf ) `'
```

Not very short, but surprisingly straightforward.

- `"\*".?g` regex `/\*/g`
- `.+_.+_ "%s"?s.#t` replace `*` with `%s` and store as *t*
- `?i len` get number of `*`s as *n*
- `` $a.~ `/\ `` create length-*n* "digit" sequences from alphabet
- `` (.t.~ sf ) `' `` use *t* to `sprintf` each sequence

Answer (score 3):

## sh + coreutils + [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/), 31 bytes

```
sed s/*/?l/g|xargs hashcat -a 3
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'*A:.»â€S
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXcvRSu/Q7sOLHjWtCf7/P1pJS0lHKR@ItZRiAQ) or [verify both test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXwf3UtRyu9Q7sPL3rUtCb4v5fO/2glrXwtJR0FJa1UrWStXC2lWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
'*A:      '# Replace all "*" in the (implicit) input-list with the lowercase alphabet
    .»     # Left-reduce the list of strings by:
      â    #  Taking the cartesian product
       €S  # Then convert each inner list to a flattened list of characters
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Minor note: `'*` could be `W` in the legacy version of 05AB1E if the input is guaranteed to always contain a `"*"`, but unfortunately the `€S` should be `€˜J` in that case, not saving any bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 91 bytes

```
\(a,j=Vectorize(\(x,y)sub('*',y,x,,,T),'y'))`if`(grepl('*',a,,,T),sapply(j(a,letters),f),a)
```

Recursive solution.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3o2M0EnWybMNSk0vyizKrUjViNCp0KjWLS5M01LXUdSp1KnR0dEI0ddQr1TU1EzLTEjTSi1ILcsCSiRCp4sSCgpxKjSygQTmpJSWpRcWaOmmaOomaUCtUc1Lz0ksyNNKAmvK1gMZwIQmkaiVr5YIEIYoXLIDQAA)

Comment: My solution uses basically the same recursive idea, so feel free to incorporate it into your answer: [65 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWNx3TbGM0ijUTMtMSNNKLUgtyNJSitWKVdIqjDWM1ddI0ihMLCnIqNXJSS0pSi4p1ikuTdAoSbaFqNDWBGGLQ3jQNJa18LSVNrpzUvPSSDI00DXWtVK1krVwtdU2oGpilAA).

Comment: Thanks! I think your solution is much better so recommend posting it.

Comment: Thanks, [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250552/55372).

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `spelling`, <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```factor
[ 1 group { "*"} ${ ALPHABET } replace [ ] product-map ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TYyxCsIwFEX3fsWjOBUquBWdKogKIoK6WDqE-KzBZxLTZCr9Epcu-gN-Tf_GlDg43Qv3nPt8Xxi3ynT96bhfb5dTuKGRSFAZ5bSQFdQaiYZCwqJhVEOND4eS418ba6POjlsQyguetIMxi6I4UUn8cvaSZn1WwCT8QgNxErcwaiDf7Fb5fHGAFgxqYhyhgBJ-f-mdaSiD_-GMyI_aCGk9goxfw9J1Ib8)

```
                              ! "*o*"
1 group                       ! { "*" "o" "*" }
{ "*"} ${ ALPHABET } replace  ! { "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" "o" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" }
[ ] product-map               ! { "aoa" "boa" ... "zoz" }
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
ẹ{"*"∧!Ạ∋|}ᵐc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KGsOKCgeG2oP/hurl7Iioi4oinIeG6oOKIi3x94bWQY///IipvIv9a)

This is a generator predicate that will unify its output with each possible combination. The TIO example uses `ᶠ - findall` to generate all answers, but in a Prolog REPL you could just press `;` repeatedly to get each answer.

#### Explanation

```
ẹ                Split the string into a list of characters
 {         }ᵐ    Map for each char:
  "*"              If the char is "*"
     ∧!              Cut (i.e. discard the "else" possibility)
        Ạ∋           The output is an element of the alphabet
          |        Else don’t modify the char
             c   Concatenate back to a string
```

The cut `!` is necessary, otherwise the predicate would also generate answers with the asterisk unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 111 bytes

I feel like it's way too long and I'm missing something big.

```js
s=>(r=s=>s[1]?.at?[...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'].flatMap(c=>r(s.slice(1)).map(p=>s[0]+c+p)):s)(s.split('*'))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Also **Python 3, 86 Bytes**:

```
def f(x):
 for i in range(26):y=x.replace('*',chr(i+97),1);f(y)if'*'in y else print(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 61 bytes

```
!s=foldl((x,y)->[x.*y...],[x<'a' ? 'a'.+(0:25)' : x for x=s])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjdtFYtt0_JzUnI0NCp0KjV17aIr9LQq9fT0YnWiK2zUE9UV7BWApJ62hoGVkammuoKVQoVCWn6RQoVtcawm1BDjnNS89JIMDUUlrXwtJc0au4KizLySnDwuhHiqVrJWLrIcRCvMHQA)

Comment: [60 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjdtFItt0_JzUnI0NCp0KjV17aIr9LQq9fT0YnWiK2zUE9UV7BUq9LQ1TE2tLAw01RWsFCoU0vKLFCpsi2M1oWa45qTmpZdkaCgqaeVrKWnW2BUUZeaV5ORxAUXytfKRRRAqU7WStXKRVUMMgzkMAA)